# storm bolt not sending out common outputs

Tags: java, apache-storm

I'm trying to find the common user between two text files using storm.The first two bolts "read" from two different text files all of the users and the third bolt searches for the common user ,but even though it seems to find them it won't print out the common user. Here's my code:

Bolt #1

```
public class ProcessAuthors extends BaseRichBolt {
      private OutputCollector collector;


      @Override
      public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
             declarer.declare(new Fields("USERNAME"));
      }

      @Override
      public void prepare(Map stormConf, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) {
             this.collector=collector;
     }

     @Override
     public void execute(Tuple input) {
         String lineFromFile=input.getString(0);

         int initialIndex=lineFromFile.indexOf("[");
         int lastIndex=lineFromFile.indexOf("]");

         String author1=lineFromFile.substring(initialIndex+1);
         String author=author1.replace("]","");
         collector.emit(input,new Values(author));
        }
     }
```

Bolt #2

```
public class FromTweetsFileToFurtherProcessing extends BaseRichBolt {
      OutputCollector collector;

      String author;

      @Override
     public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
            declarer.declare(new Fields("USERNAME"));
     }

    @Override
    public void prepare(Map stormConf, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) {
          this.collector=collector;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Tuple input) {
            String lineFromFile = input.getString(0);

            String author="";

            String[] splitLineFromFileIntoFields =      lineFromFile.split(",");

            for (int i = 0; i < splitLineFromFileIntoFields.length; i++) {
                 if (splitLineFromFileIntoFields[i].startsWith("\"tweetAuthor\"")) {
                      this.author = removeTwoWordsFromString(splitLineFromFileIntoFields[i], "\"tweetAuthor\":\"", "\"");
            }
    }

    collector.emit(input,new Values(this.author));
}
```

Bolt #3

```
public class SearchForTheAuthorsTweetData extends BaseRichBolt{
OutputCollector collector;
List<String>authors=new ArrayList<String>();
List<String>temp=new ArrayList<String>();

String author1;String author2;

@Override
public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
    declarer.declare(new Fields("USERNAME"));
}


@Override
public void prepare(Map stormConf, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) {
    this.collector=collector;
}

@Override
public void execute(Tuple input) {
    final String sourceComponent = input.getSourceComponent();


    if ("PROCESS_AUTHORS".equals(sourceComponent)) {

        author1 = input.getString(0);
        authors.add(author1);
    }




    if ("PROCESS_TWEETS_FROM_MONGODB".equals(sourceComponent)) {
        author2 = input.getString(0);
        temp.add(author2);

    }

    if(author2!=null && author1!=null){
        System.out.println("USER: "+author2);
        System.out.println("AUTHOR: "+author1);

        if(author2.equals(author1)){
            System.out.println("COMMON AUTHOR: "+author2);
            collector.emit(input,new Values(author1));
        }
    }
```

Topology

```
 public class TheAuthorsAndTheirTweetData {
 public static void main(String[]args) throws Exception{
    TopologyBuilder topologyBuilder=new TopologyBuilder();

    topologyBuilder.setSpout("READ_AUTHORS_MONGO",new ReadLinesFromTextFile("anAuthor.txt"),1);
    topologyBuilder.setBolt("PROCESS_AUTHORS",new ProcessAuthors(),2).shuffleGrouping("READ_AUTHORS_MONGO");

    topologyBuilder.setSpout("READ_TWEETS_FROM_MONGODB",new ReadLinesFromTextFile("tweets.txt"),1);

    topologyBuilder.setBolt("PROCESS_TWEETS_FROM_MONGODB",new FromTweetsFileToFurtherProcessing(),2).shuffleGrouping("READ_TWEETS_FROM_MONGODB");


    topologyBuilder.setBolt("SEARCH_1",new SearchForTheAuthorsTweetData(),8).fieldsGrouping("PROCESS_AUTHORS", new Fields("USERNAME")).fieldsGrouping("PROCESS_TWEETS_FROM_MONGODB", new Fields("USERNAME"));


    Config config=new Config();
    if(args!=null && args.length>0){
        config.setNumWorkers(10);
        config.setNumAckers(5);
        config.setMaxSpoutPending(100);
        StormSubmitter.submitTopology(args[0], config, topologyBuilder.createTopology());
    }else{
        LocalCluster localCluster=new LocalCluster();
        localCluster.submitTopology("Test",config,topologyBuilder.createTopology());
        Utils.sleep(1*60*60*1000);
        localCluster.killTopology("Test");
        localCluster.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to implement something "similiar" to the word count; where in your bolt #3 you keep something in memory where you track all the authors and if they showed up in the text file or in the mongodb data source.

Answer (score 0):

Your third bolt will only find a common author if that author is contained in two subsequent tuples, one from bolt one and one from bolt two.  Change your code to look something like this:

```
if ("PROCESS_TWEETS_FROM_MONGODB".equals(sourceComponent)) {
    author2 = input.getString(0);
    temp.add(author2);
    if (authors.contains(author2)) {
         // common author - emit it
    }
}
```

Note this probably won't scale as you have to read the contents of both files into bolt three's memory.

Comment: I tried that but i kept getting only one username instead of all of them